# Update user attribute in Laravel calling a function on controller by pressing a button on blade view but without refresh page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I hava blade Laravel view where I have a button at the click of which I would like to update some user attributes. I have implemented in the controller a method to which pass the values ​​to be reported and saved on the user, but I do not want to update the page or change the URL. What is the correct method to do this?

Thank you.

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/updateUserPreference/{plan_compact_view}', [NutritionalPlanController::class, 'up
dateUserPreference'])->name('updateUserPreference');
```

**blade view**

```
@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn_view_type').click(function (e) {
                //AJAX Call update user preference
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'updateUserPreference',
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function () {
                        console.log("done");
                     
                    },error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                         console.log("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

**Update 2**

```
        const planCompactView = true;
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: '/updateUserPreference/${planCompactView}',
            method: 'post',
            /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller */
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {},
            success: function () {
                console.log("done");
                //do something
            },error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log(xhr.status+" ,"+" "+ajaxOptions+", "+thrownError);
            }
        });
```

Now the error message in console is: "200 , parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: You need to make an ajax call when the button is clicked

Comment: @Donkarnash Thank you. 
I have this error in console using an ajax call:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Comment: Please post the code of your routes file, code with ajax call and controller. It's difficult to guess what could be causing the error without having a look at the code

Comment: @Donkarnash Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url in your ajax code snippet need to be changed to match the url defined in routes file

You also need to get the value for route parameter `plan_compact_view` and append it to the url in js snippet

```
@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const planCompactView = 'get the value';

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn_view_type').click(function (e) {
                //AJAX Call update user preference
                $.ajax({
                    url: `/updateUserPreference/${planCompactView}`,
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function () {
                        console.log("done");
                     
                    },error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                         console.log("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: whitout headers i have error 419  than i have added this. But now the error is: "200 , parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" as reported in "Update 2" of the request.

Comment: try with non empty object for data like data:{foo: 'bar'} and see if the error changes

Comment: How about including e.preventDefault() as first line in .click() just to ensure that normal submit doesn't occur. And try removing dataType: "JSON" and see if error changes

Comment: Removing dataType:JSON it's works! Thank you.